# PowerShell Function within Array Comprehension

Tags: powershell

I am parsing all logins for a Windows system ($system). I'm trying to get a tuple/array of domain, user, session id.

```
$logged_on_users = Get-WmiObject Win32_LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $system
```

I'm then calling the type's function to pull out two variables (Antecedent and Depedent) within each value:

```
$all_user_sessions = @()
foreach ($x in $logged_on_users){
  $t = @()
  $t += $x.GetPropertyValue("Antecedent").tostring()
  $t += $x.GetPropertyValue("Dependent").tostring()
  $all_user_sessions += $t
}
```

What is the syntax for a one-line Array Comprehension (if it's even possible)? I have:

```
$all_user_sessions = ($logged_on_users | % { @($_.GetPropertyValue("Antecedent").tostring(), $_.GetPropertyValue("Dependent").tostring() ) })
```

When I add

```
foreach ($s in $all_user_sessions){
  echo $s.GetType().FullName
}
```

The type is a String, not an Array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is going to sound a little weird, but you need to add a comma before the array in your `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
$all_user_sessions = ($logged_on_users | % { ,@($_.GetPropertyValue("Antecedent").tostring(), $_.GetPropertyValue("Dependent").tostring() ) })
```

As your code is written you're adding everything to a single array. Placing the comma like that will create an array (actually an object) of each index.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. I'm just used to Python.